# How to invoke a Javascript function from F#

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

I am very new to F# and i do more work with Javascript.
I just want to know whether it is possible to call a javascript function from F#.
Of course this Question may not show minimum effort. But i am just asking for an Idea
Thanks

Comment: This question is really vague. Are you trying to use a Javascript runtime like V8 or IronJS, are you cross-compiling F# to javascript, or are you using ASP.NET with F#?

Comment: @Wesley Wiser Thanks for your response.. My doubt is basically i want to develop a Client side application that will take inputs and should generate a HTML page through javascript with using jQuery or any such type of libraries.. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you seen WebSharper? It is basically a web development framework based on ASP.NET and F#. It will allow you to use F# and JavaScript freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# is mainly a server-side language. This means that compiled F# code runs on the server - you can expose some functionality written in F# as a REST service and call it from JavaScript using the usual AJAX style call.

If you want to follow this path, then the easiest option is to write the server-side code using some framework like ASP.NET MVC ([this article explains how to use F# with MVC](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-mvc-web.aspx), examples of writing REST services mostly use C#, but it should be easy to translate them), or you can use `HttpListener` to write your own lightweight web server in F# (you can find [some example here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Chapter-2-Concurrent-645370c3) - the website currently has just source code, but there will be links to articles that explain it soon).

Alternatively, there are some projects that allow you to write code F# and have it translated to JavaScript. Then you can run your entire F# program on the client-side (without any server). The JavaScript generated from F# can be probably also invoked from usual JavaScript code. Take a look at [WebSharper](http://www.websharper.com/) and the [FSharp.JavaScript](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/13250.aspx) project.

Answer (score 0):

In general - rather not. You can call other .NET libraries or native code through platform invoke. Although, one possible solution for your problem would be using a Javascript parser, which would give you the possibility of exchanging object with your f# code and running it. One library you could consider would be [Javascript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) which is based on Google's V8 engine and probably will work. Although, I have never used it for such task, so I can't give you any specifics.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. My doubt is basically i want to develop a Client side application that will take inputs and should generate a HTML page through javascript with using jQuery or any such type of libraries.. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific with "take input (what input?) and should generate a HTML page through js with Jquery? (what do you mean by "through js"? you want javascript to do modify html through DOM? Normally, I'd expect javascript to do this interactively (because that's what it's meant for)). My doubt here is that you probably won't be able to just load jQuery through such engine, or it won't be that easy, as it's heavily dependent on being bound to a web page and it's DOM to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is basically i want to develop a Client side application that
>   will take inputs and should generate a HTML page through javascript
>   with using jQuery or any such type of libraries.. Is this possible?

Yes, you can use F# to write a desktop app which generates HTML including Javascript. There are also controls such as [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) which you can use to display the generated web page.

Alternatively, you could use [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started) which is designed to generate web pages and allows you to write web apps in .Net ([including F#](http://tomasp.net/articles/aspnet-fsharp-intro.aspx)).